Is it possible to template the parameters of Ansible's uri module with Jinja2?
I am just wondering whether it's possible to use jinja2 template within URI module.
I have tried something like this:
- name: update checkpoint members asset field
  uri: |
      [{% for item in device_result_set if item.Name in checkpointPairs %}
      {{  url: api_host""api_target""item.ID
          method: PUT
          validate_certs: 'no'
          status_code: 200
          headers:
            Content-Type: 'application/json'
            Authorization: 'Custom' api_key
          body_format: 'json'
          body: item}},
      {% endfor %}]
  register: put_result
  no_log: False
  tags: put

The reason why I am trying to use Jinja2 template is to optimize the loop process which takes a huge amount of time - I expect two thousands of items and the task slows down after 50 - 60 items.
Or maybe there is a different mechanism I am not aware off?

"I am just wondering whether it's possible to use Jinja2 Template within URI module.", yes it is, depending on what you try achieve. In example on the body only. But not in the way you are showing here, on the module parameter itself.

In any case the approach you are trying is not appropriate to "optimize loop process which takes huge amount of time ...  thousands of items and task slows down after 50 - 60 items".

Templating parameters from a dictionary is something possible but highly discouraged, due to the security concerns you might face if dealing with compromised data:

You can set all of a task’s arguments from a dictionary-typed variable. This technique can be useful in some dynamic execution scenarios. However, it introduces a security risk. We do not recommend it, so Ansible issues a warning when you do something like this
#...
vars:
  usermod_args:
    name: testuser
    state: present
    update_password: always
tasks:
- user: '{{ usermod_args }}'


Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-is-it-unsafe-to-bulk-set-task-arguments-from-a-variable
This said, I do not see a need to actually template the parameters, in this specific case, you could use a normal loop filtered with selectattr:
- name: update checkpoint members asset field
  uri: 
    url: "{{ api_host }}{{ api_target }}{{ item.ID }}"
    method: PUT
    validate_certs: 'no'
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: "Custom {{ api_key }}"
    body_format: json
    body: "{{ item }}"
  register: put_result
  loop: "{{ device_result_set | selectattr('Name', 'in', checkpointPairs) }}"
  no_log: False
  tags: put
  

